# How can I add a custom stylesheet to my custom theme?

Tags: custom, styles

I am losing my mind because I am following guidance in documentation but literally nothing works.

I added a custom theme that references luma. my directory structure is /app/design/frontend/Localstretch/luma_child

In my luma_child/web/css folder I put localstretch.css

In my /app/design/frontend/Localstretch/luma_child/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml

I added the following:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="css/localstretch.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  />
    </head>
</page>
```

I cleared cache php bin/magento cache:flush
then did php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

but I still can't see my css being loaded.

I had also deleted folder for another theme I added but that is still showing in admin. What gives?

Comment: make sure you have selected child theme as current theme, also verify also theme is not virtual, you can verify in theme table.

Comment: - check for how to create Theme: https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/frontend-core/guide/themes/create-storefront/ 

      - And check for how to add CSS file: https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/frontend-core/guide/css/themes/

Comment: Hi, I actually got it working but I don't know how. I just ran a whole bunch of commands like magento something:di:something and a bunch of other commands I found online.

Comment: It May be Running the CLI commands might have updated some dependencies or packages that were needed for the CSS to work properly, or CLI commands you ran might have cleared the cache, which could have resolved any caching issues that were preventing your CSS from loading